# Product of sums into a sum of products

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Any idea on how I can get an expression in the form of sum of products from the following one?:
\begin{equation}
\prod_{i=1}^M \left(\sum_{n=1}^i x_n\right)
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1):

$$
\prod_{i=1}^M \sum_{n=1}^i x_n=\sum_{n=1}^M\prod_{i=n}^M y_{ni}
=\sum_{n=1}^M y_{nn}\cdots y_{nM},
$$
where $y_{ni}=x_n$ for $n\le i$ and $y_{ni}=0$ for $n>i$.

Comment: Before studying it more deeply, $y_{ni}=0$ for n>i, or $y_{ni}=1$ for n>i?

Comment: It must must be zero, not $1$. Just in order to be able to make the "usual" change of variables.